# Python (mongoengine) : missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm making a database query to fetch a document thus :

```
class Dags(Document):
    somefield = DictField()

def parse_doc(self, dag_doc):
    print("...")
    print(dag_doc)
    dag = dag_doc.to_mongo().to_dict()
    dag['_id'] = str(dag_doc['_id'])
    return dag

def findDagById(dag_id):
    dag_doc = Dags.objects.get(id=ObjectId(dag_id))
    return parse_doc(dag_doc)
```

I get this error :

> TypeError: parse_doc() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'dag_doc'

I am not able to understand why should I get this error. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Seems that it's bad indentation for `parse_doc`, it should be class method.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov : Uhh no I've purposefully defined both the functions outside the class.

Comment: In that case you no need `self` as first parameter  for `parse_doc` .

Comment: Ah man. How could I.. thanks a lot.